# JNDI Naming Uniqueness?

Tags: java, spring, wildfly, jndi, wildfly-10

Is it necessary for JNDI names to be unique for the EJBs?

Two EJBs in my code referring to the same remote file, So it has same JNDI name
which throws this exception

> Invocation of init method failed; javax.naming.NamingException wildfly

and BEAN and Remote are in two different jars

Comment: Please show your code. Your question is currently very vague.

Comment: **JNDI names have to be unique**. They are used to identify resources inside app server. May be you have the same alias name defined for your beans or the module name is the same. Please provide more code.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on deployment. JNDI names have to be unique only with same Jave EE module only. So if you have two ejb-jar files within one EAR, each would get it is own namespace, and you refer to them in format

java:namespace/[app-name]/module-name/bean-name/[!fully-qualified-interface-name]

If you deploy your jar inside .war file, then your ejb will not be independent Java EE module, and will share it's JNDI namespace with .war.